# How to extract a substring from a class using CSS selectors?

Tags: html, css

I have a Hugo-generated static website and in each code snippet I want to place the language name in the bottom right.

I am already able to get the whole class (`language-x`) in the `code` tag using a CSS selector but I want to capture only the language name from the class name, not the whole class.

This is a minimum working example of what I have so far:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gZWWNP

```
<html>

<style>
pre {
    background: #26282C;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-left: .8em;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    overflow: auto;
    tab-size: 4;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-left: 5px solid #F27563;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

code[class*="language-"]:after,
pre[class*="language-"]:after {
  content: attr(class);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: smaller;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
</style>

<body>

<pre>
<code class="language-perl6">class Person {
    has Str $.firstname;
    has Str $.lastname;
    has Str $.age;
}
</code>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

In this case, instead of `language-perl6` I'd like to display just `perl6`. I want to keep this as minimal as possible without using any additional tool besides CSS or probably vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update the `content` value unfortunately, but you can create a new `attr` via javascript and use this within your CSS. I have referenced a new attribute within your CSS - `content: attr(short-lang);`, and then written some pure javascript to convert your class and assign it to the new attribute.

I've created the code so it works for `pre` and `code` elements as this is what your CSS suggests is needed. I added a `pre` with a class to the demo.

> I would seriously consider storing the language in it's own attribute, rather than as a class as if you have to add any other class this code will also display those classes.

```js
// Get all code and pre elements
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('code,pre');

// Cycle through each code element
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    // Load language from class
    var lang = elements[i].getAttribute("class");
    
    // Remove 'language-' if lang is not empty
    if (lang != null ) {
      lang = lang.substr(lang.length - (lang.length-9));
    }
    
    // Create 'short-lang' parameter for element
    elements[i].setAttribute("short-lang", lang);
    
}
```

```css
pre {
    background: #26282C;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-left: .8em;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    overflow: auto;
    tab-size: 4;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-left: 5px solid #F27563;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

code[class*="language-"]:after,
pre[class*="language-"]:after {
  content: attr(short-lang);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: smaller;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>


<body>

<pre>
<code class="language-perl6">
class Person {
    has Str $.firstname;
    has Str $.lastname;
    has Str $.age;
}

</code>

</pre>

<pre class="language-perl9">
class Person {
    has Str $.firstname;
    has Str $.lastname;
    has Str $.age;
}


</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works wonderfully. I'm unsure how I'd instruct Hugo to store the language in its own attribute though but I'll leave it for another time. Thanks!